# Por que usar short?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

O tipo `short` corresponde a um inteiro de 16 bits - é literalmente açúcar sintático para o tipo `Int16`.

Os processadores atuais são todos 64 bits, mesmo nas máquinas mais *low-end*. Algumas máquinas antigas ainda têm processadores com arquiteturas de 32 bits.

Até onde entendo (e me corrijam se eu estiver enganado), é mais rápido trabalhar com um inteiro do tamanho da arquitetura do processador na maioria dos casos, devido as otimizações da CPU. I.e.: se eu estiver a somar inteiros de 16 bits, os registros da CPU recebem e tratam blocos de 32 ou 64 bits de qualquer forma, e depois ainda há o trabalho de se zerar todos os bits além do décimo sexto no resultado (supondo não haver tratamento de estouro).

Então, em que situações eu deveria usar o tipo `short`, e por que?

Comment: EU não gosto de shorts. Prefiro bermudas mesmo. #PiadaNerdDoAno

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Em geral não há porque usar um `short` em aplicações, especialmente em .NET.

Um caso para usar é se você tiver um volume **muito** grande de dados numéricos dentro da faixa que cabe em um `short` (-32768 à 32767). Repito, em um volume muito grande, diminuir de 4 para 2 bytes pode dar alguma vantagem. Mas note que esse volume precisa realmente ser muito grande mesmo. É muito raro ser necessário. E mesmo que o volume seja grande também precisa ter a necessidade (não ter memória suficiente para usar um `int`). Senão, é micro-otimização que não vale o esforço.

Se você não sabe como será usado na prática pode ser interessante usar. Bibliotecas costumam usar, porque pode ser que alguém vá usar aquele objeto que tem um número em grande quantidade, você não tem controle sobre isso.

Outro ponto é que essa otimização de uso da memória é válida quando praticamente só vai usar dados `short` nas suas estruturadas de dados. Se a informação estiver em estruturas mais complexas, onde o campo do tipo `short` for apenas uma parte do consumo de memória, principalmente se a estrutura for de um tipo de referência (objetos alocados no *heap*), o ganho certamente não ajudará muito no consumo de memória.

**Dependendo** da plataforma e a implementação do [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) pode até ter uma piora na performance usando `short`. Costuma haver um ganho quando o tamanho do dados equivale ao tamanho da palavra do processador. Mas não tente se valer de uma informação sobre implementação, ela pode mudar sem aviso. Se tem um volume muito grande dados que precisam ser manipulados de forma intensa o mais comum é que tenha algum ganho principalmente pela capacidade de guardar mais elementos (o dobro) em cache usando um `short` do que um `int`.

Você pode ter perdas, em alguns casos, também por ter que fazer conversões desnecessárias. Boa parte do .NET está melhor preparado para trabalhar com `int`. Mas o oposto pode tornar o `short` mais interessante. Se você sabe que vai usar muitos métodos que primariamente trabalham com `short` o seu uso pode evitar as conversões, mas são raros métodos.

Um caso típico para evitar conversões é quando se está trabalhando com interoperabilidade com código externo que espere um `short`, principalmente com código C/C++, gerenciado ou não. **Interoperabilidade é o caso principal para o qual o `short` foi criado no .NET**.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Alguma coisa que eu respondi está errado? Não entendi o voto negativo.

Answer (score 16):

A [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13932/215) já dá uma excelente visão geral, apenas gostaria de complementar a seguinte parte:

> O mais comum se tem um volume muito grande dados que precisam ser manipulados de forma intensa é que tenha algum ganho mais pela capacidade de guardar mais elementos em cache usando um `short` do que um `int`.

De um modo geral, a influência de um bom uso da cache na performance de um sistema é algo pra não ser subestimado. Muitas vezes se presta muita atenção à performance local (fazer o cast) e se esquece a performance global (num *cache miss*, diversos ciclos são desperdiçados - mais do que o *overhead* de uma instrução extra ou duas, dependendo do caso).

Nada disso contradiz a resposta mencionada: somente se o volume de dados for grande é que há vantagem (embora talvez discorde no que seria "muito" grande). Além disso, é bastante diferente você ter, por exemplo, um array de objetos:

```
class MeuObjeto {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    Baz baz;
    short s;
}
MeuObjeto[] array = new MeuObjeto[10000];
```

Ou um array de `short`s:

```
short[] array = new short[10000];
```

No primeiro caso, a economia de espaço é mínima - ainda que os objetos estejam em posições contíguas de memória (dependendo do caso, podem não estar) - e isso se o alinhamento da memória não eliminar essa diferença de espaço. O uso de `short` em vez de `int` não vai ter um impacto significativo nas *cache  misses*, de modo que o *overhead* das operações de cast não terá nenhuma contrapartida positiva.

Já no segundo caso, a história é outra: vai demorar duas vezes mais para você ter um *cache miss* se você estiver acessando esses elementos sequencialmente, comparado com um array de `int`. Mesmo para acessos aleatórios, a chance do dado que você quer já estar na cache é duas vezes maior. De modo que, ainda que cada operação individual seja um pouquinho menos eficiente, os ciclos que você "economiza" evitando os *misses* pode compensar - tornando a operação completa mais rápida.

(Em todo caso, continua valendo o conselho de evitar otimizações prematuras / micro otimizações)

Comment: Sem dúvida o short sendo usando em conjunto com outros dados perde grande parte da vantagem. Por isso que eu disse que em raros cenários seria útil essa otimização, teria que usar short puro. Vou mais além, não sei como funciona o alinhamento neste caso, mas pode nem haver ganho de espaço em uma classe. Excelente detalhamento.

Answer (score 7):

Não que fique mais lento, pois a CPU mesmo sendo de 64 bits, ainda possui instruções para lidar com tipos numéricos menores do que o nativo.

O char do .Net por exemplo, possui 16 bits, o que equivale a um short/ushort.

A vantagem real que vejo em usar os tipos inteiros menores, seria para economizar memória no caso da necessidade de um array com milhões de itens na memória... ou até mesmo bilhões.

Fora isso, é mais pratico usar o tipo `int` mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

O tipo short garante *no mínimo* 16 bits -- não chega a ser um sinônimo para int16_t.

Só vejo uso para ele quando você precisa interagir com um valor ou estrutura que também seja short, como alguma tabela de hardware, driver de dispositivo ou API de baixo nível. Por exemplo, numa conexão TCP/IP a porta é unsigned short (http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html)

Também acontece muito ao lidar-se com dados vindos da rede, normalmente em conjunção com htons(). Quando se lida com rede, o melhor é usar os tipos de tamanho garantido, tipo int16_t ou uint16_t, que garantem o tamanho exato em bits.

Comment: +1 pelos exemplos de quando se utiliza, porém discordo quanto a garantia de tamanho - a [documentação oficial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx) menciona ser uma forma mais curta de se referir ao tipo [System.Int16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int16.aspx).

Comment: @Renan, ele não viu que a pergunta é para C#. A resposta dele faz sentido para C, não para C#. Curioso que 3 pessoas não perceberam isso também.

Comment: @Maniero realmente, só percebi porque você falou. No entanto, acredito que a informação sobre drivers e API's de baixo nível procede.

Comment: @Renan concordo, até respondi isso também.

Comment: Verdade, não percebi que era pra C# :(

Answer (score 3):

> Até onde entendo (e me corrijam se eu estiver enganado), é mais rápido trabalhar com um inteiro do tamanho da arquitetura do processador na maioria dos casos, devido as otimizações da CPU.

Realmente, definir variáveis do tipo short ou char é meio que um desperdício, já que essas variáveis vão viver em um registrador onde cabem bem mais bits. Em geral, se usa short ou char para dados armazenados na memória, onde o tamanho do registrador não importa. O tempo que se gasta para transferir um short da memória pra um registrador é o mesmo tempo que se gasta para ler um int, mas o vetor de shorts vai gastar metade do espaço que o vetor de int.