# Por que usar Int onde cabe Byte ou Short?

Tags: java, tipagem, memória, int

Por que não utilizar o tipo primitivo `byte` ou `short` pra armazenar uma idade de pessoa ao invés de utilizar o tipo `int`? Os dois citados consumem menos memoria? Não seria melhor?

Comment: Isso é algo que fica ao critério do desenvolvedor, em analisar quais tipos de dados são mais adequados ao contexto da aplicação que está desenvolvendo. Não existe uma convenção que diz ter que usar tipo int quando se quer representar em um atributo a idade de uma pessoa.

Comment: È por que em muitos dos exemplos a galera so usa o int, e quase nao vejo exemplos com o tipo byte o short ..

Comment: Relacionado? [Por que usar short?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13930/3117)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nada impede de você usar isso.

O que ocorre no mercado (pelo menos já vi isso em três lugares) é que as pessoas padronizam.

Em um desses lugares era VB6 com oracle, eles tinham toda uma camada de persistência deles para fazer tudo o que precisavam de acesso a banco, era um sistema grande, mais de 5000 terminais. No caso deles a utilização de alguns tipos diferentes davam erro nessa camada de persistência deles, e eles não queria alterar nada.

Se isso é bom ou ruim eu não vou entrar no mérito.

O que eu acho é que hoje com todas as ferramentas que existem vale a pena pensar em como armazenar as informações de uma forma mais limpa, correta, bonita.

Comment: Bem didatica sua resposta, sei que pra persistir com banco ultilizamos os wrappers como Integer, Double etcc..., mas tipo nem sempre precisamos ultiliza o mesmo pra guarda uma idade, venho estudando java e noto que em todos os tutoriais a galera so usa int pra armazena variaveis que recebem numeros decimais entre 0 e 100 e fico sem entender o por que , entende ?

Comment: Falando em tutorial você está falando de feijão com arroz, é mais fácil para todos entenderem, mas quando se fala em sistemas de grande porte você tem frameworks rodando tanto de terceiros quanto particulares e isso muitas vezes dita o que será usado, a sua ideia de usar os tipos certos é uma excelente ideia e você deve continuar a pensar assim. Só não seja fanático caso algum dia veja alguma coisa diferente :)

Comment: rsrsr Obrigado pelo feedback ..

Answer (score 5):

A resposta simples é: porque não precisa fazer esta economia.

Tem certeza que consome menos memória? Se ele for usado em uma estrutura de dados, o que é bem comum em código real, haverá alinhamento e esse consumo menor pode desaparecer.

Vamos dizer que tem o ganho, ajuda alguma coisa real? Ainda mais usando Java que é devoradora de memória por outros motivos. É tentar conter pingos de um enxurrada.

Em algumas arquiteturas é mais rápido processar um inteiro do que um tipo de outro tamanho. Quer ter esta perda? Imagine quanto se gasta tendo que fazer conversões em diversos casos para tornar o código genérico ou compatibilizar com o que existe pronto.

Claro que se precisa do ganho, tem que medir, posso te adiantar que pra maioria dos casos não vale o esforço ou não há ganho em fazer isto. Esta é a razão das pessoas preferirem usar o jeito mais geral e padrão. Usar um tipo menor é uma otimização e para toda otimização deve haver uma boa justificativa real, nada de especulação.

Para mais detalhes tem uma resposta minha em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13930/101). É C#, mas vale para Java.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entende mas a minha duvida foi em relação ao basico mesmo, que muita galera nao faz uso desses dois tipos .. Dificilmente voce vai ver alguem ultilizando mesmo em exemplos basico, como crie uma variavel que armazene a idade de uma pessoa o tipo byte e short .

Comment: Acho que não entendeu. Eu expliquei isso. Mas se você quer saber de forma mais explícita porque não se usa em exemplos básicos, é porque já que eles não fazem nada útil, pra que tentar otimizar? As pessoas não tentam otimizar algo justamente porque elas são pragmáticas, sabem o que estão fazendo e sabem que não precisa fazer isto, que não há ganho real ou se houver, ele é inútil. Claro que nem todas. Algumas fazem certo porque copiaram as que sabem fazer.Copiar o que os outros fazem pode dar certo ou não,vai da sorte.Por isso que é importante saber o que está fazendo para tomar a decisão certa