# É possível converter um número de 16 bits para um único byte?

Tags: c#, byte

Este código:

```
Int16 numero = 2017;
byte m = (byte) numero;
```

`m` será `225`. De forma inversa, como obtenho **2017** a partir de `m`  novamente?

Comment: 16 bits são 2 bytes. Não tem como converter sem jogar informação fora.

Comment: Um bom exemplo de como armazenar números em menos bits do que a potência de 2 equivalente são os floats (também chamados de [Minifloats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifloat) nesse caso). Isso é algo feito no dia a dia em inúmeras situações onde não se necessita exatidão - obviamente alguma perda vai ter em parte dos valores. Uma pesquisa rápida por `8 bit float` é um bom ponto de partida. E tem aplicações reais interessantes, não é só "teoria computacional" não: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/04/15/eight-bit-floating-point/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Parece que está te faltando a base conceitual sobre como valores são codificados em binário.

Se cada dígito binário só pode ser zero ou um, um dígito binário só permite codificar dois valores. Da mesma maneira, dois dígitos permitem codificar até 4 valores:

```
00 - 0
01 - 1
10 - 2
11 - 3
```

A regra geral é que a quantidade de valores que um número binário de determinado comprimento n é capaz de codificar é x = 2<sup>n</sup>. Portanto, em 8 bits (1 byte) você consegue codificar 256 valores distintos. No caso de inteiros, pode ser de -128 a 127 de 0 a 255, ou outra alguma outra divisão mais exótica. Mas de qualquer maneira, não cabem mais que 256 valores em 1 byte.

Assim, se você tem um valor que precisa de mais de 1 byte para ser armazenado, não tem como fazê-lo caber em 1 byte sem perder informação. No seu exemplo de `2017`, por exemplo, a conversão dá 255 porque é o maior inteiro que cabe em 1 byte. Qualquer valor maior que 255 dá esse mesmo resultado ao ser convertido para byte, e assim não tem como desfazer a operação, já que inúmeros valores (infinitos, na verdade) dão esse mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 14):

## Não tem espaço

Você está querendo pegar algo de 1Kg e guardar em um recipiente de 500g, vai jogar fora 500g, aí você quer ter o 1Kg de volta. Só existe uma possibilidade, guardar os 500g em outro lugar. Mas pra que fazer isso? Não tem sentido. Se precisa manter a informação completa, use ela completa.

Em um tipo `byte` cabem 8 bits, como o bit só tem 2 estados, 2 elevado a 8 temos uma combinação de 256 números diferentes, então em um `byte` não podemos representar um número maior que 255, já que começa do 0.

Um [`short`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13930/101) possui 2 bytes (16 bits), podendo representar 65536 números diferentes. Mas tem uma coisa diferente do `byte`, ele é sinalizado, ou seja existe um bit indicando se é negativo, então o maior número possível positivo é 32783.

Então não tem quantidade de bits suficiente em um `byte` para representar 2017 que precisaria um mínimo de 11 bits, mas como não dá para reservar memória com um byte quebrado, 16 bits é adotado.

Na verdade mesmo o uso de um `short` talvez deva ser evitado. Em alguns casos onde o ganho de memória ocorrerá de fato, e [poucos casos ocorre e é necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106825/101), em geral é pior tentar usar um tipo menor do que o mais adequado para o processador, então deixe um `int` (`Int32`), a não ser que tenha certeza que terá ganho.

## Solução alternativa

Agora, se precisar realmente reduzir o tamanho, o que eu duvido que seja tão necessário assim, é possível adotar algum critério conforme o que for usar. Você pode jogar fora uma informação que sabe que pode ser recuperada depois por convenção. Isto dá certo em alguns casos.

Por exemplo, está usando 2017, acredito que isso seja um ano completo com século, mas talvez não precise do século, então subtraia 2000 e guarde só o ano que cabe um um `byte`. Se tiver anos de antes de 2000, pode subtrair 1900, claro que o que estiver acima de 100 você sabe que é século 21, o que está abaixo é século 20.

De forma simplificada seria algo assim:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        short numero = 2017;
        var m = new ShortYear(numero);
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
}
//provavelmente teria implemnetações de operadores, outros métodos e das interfaces
//IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<ShortYear>, IEquatable<ShortYear> e outras
public struct ShortYear {
    public byte Year;
    public const short Century = 1900;
    public ShortYear(short value) {
        Contract.Ensures(value >= Century && value < Century + 256);
        Year = (byte)(value - Century);
    }
    public ShortYear(int value) {
        Contract.Ensures(value >= Century && value < Century + 256);
        Year = (byte)(value - Century);
    }
    public static implicit operator short(ShortYear value) => (short)(value.Year + Century);
    public static implicit operator int(ShortYear value) => value.Year + Century;
    public override int GetHashCode() => Year.GetHashCode();
    public override String ToString() => (Year + Century).ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s47Cs4). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lS2AKp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/ShortYear.cs).

Eu ainda acho muita gambiarra pra provavelmente pouco ganho. Você teria que ficar controlando isso em toda aplicação. Ou poderia criar um tipo de um byte que abstraia tudo isto, o que ainda provavelmente será muito esforço para pouco ganho, como não há contexto não dá para afirmar.

Seria possível usar alguma outra forma como um tipo de ponto flutuante binário com 1 byte, fora do padrão [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), mas ele poderia representar menos inteiros ainda, e decimais que não servem para nada neste caso, poderia ser em casos extremamentes restritos com outra exigência onde não precisa de exatidão decimal, pode ter pouca precisão, e bem poucos inteiros.

Answer (score 11):

Como um byte é composto geralmente* de oito bits, o maior valor que você pode representar em geral é 255 mesmo.

Explicação: números inteiros são representados em geral como somas de potências de 2. Cada bit com valor zero representa zero mesmo, e cada bit com valor 1 representa o valor 2<sup>n</sup>, onde *n* é a posição (geralmente da direita para a esquerda) do bit zero-indexada.

Seguem alguns valores para exemplo:

```
0000 0001 = 1
0000 0010 = 2
0000 0100 = 4
0000 0101 = 5
0001 0000 = 32
0010 0001 = 33
```

Etc., etc., até o maior valor que é 255 quando a disposição dos bits é a seguinte:

```
1111 1111 = 255
```

Pois 255 = 2<sup>7</sup> + 2<sup>6</sup> + 2<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup>.

Então, para representarmos quaisquer valores maiores que isso, precisamos de mais bits. Por esse motivo os tipos numéricos da maioria das linguagens tem tamanhos variando de dezesseis a sessenta e quatro bits.

Infelizmente, exatamente por esse motivo, não é possível extrair um valor inteiro maior do que 255 a partir de apenas oito bits.

Talvez fosse possível com [números de ponto flutuante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219774/1658), mas em geral o menor tipo de ponto flutuante, o *float*, costuma ocupar ao menos quatro bytes em memória. Além disso, você ainda correria o risco de não obter o resultado desejado devido a problemas de precisão, caso deseje implementar ponto flutuante de um byte na marra.

Portanto:

- Se você quer utilizar o tipo *byte* por motivos de compactação, é melhor rever suas estratégias;
- Se você precisa utilizar o tipo *byte* por quaisquer outros motivos (i.e.: tarefa de casa), você vai precisar de mais bytes.

*Eu não estou fazendo piadinhas de mal-gosto aqui, [bytes de tamanhos diferentes existem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5516161/2263584) apesar de serem quase tão raros quanto mundiais do Palmeiras.

Answer (score 3):

Um valor de 16 bits é melhor representado como um short invés de int para usar BitConvert.GetBytes(short).

Por isso, como alternativa:

```
byte lowByte = (byte) (numero & 0xff);
byte highByte = (byte) ((numero >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 2):

Impossível colocar 16 bits em 1 byte. O que você pode fazer é colocar em um array de bytes com BitConverter e depois fazer o processo ao contrário.

```
    Int16 numero = 2017;
    var StrToByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(numero);
    byte[] temp = new byte[4];
    StrToByte.CopyTo(temp, 0);
    StrToByte = temp;
    var i = BitConverter.ToInt32(StrToByte, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```